# Add a cookie before invoking PhantomJS?

Tags: java, selenium, cookies, web-scraping, phantomjs

I want to add a cookie before executing phantomJS, is this possible?

```
String url="https://www.google.com";
String driverPath="F:/jar/phantomjs.exe";
String JsPath="F:/jar/exec_getPageSource.js";

String exec=driverPath+" "+JsPath+" "+url;

String pageSource="";
Process process=null;
BufferedReader brin=null;
try {
    process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(exec);
    brin=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line="";
    while ((line=brin.readLine())!=null){
        pageSource+=line;
    }
    process.waitFor();
    System.out.println(pageSource);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```